# Fetch() network error when fetching resource using a node.js API

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to use fetch() to POST an object of arrays in javascript to a nodeJS API. I keep getting the following error 'TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.[Learn More] main.js:121:3' and I'm not sure how to fix it.

[Here's](https://pastebin.com/YQgijj5F) my code for the related files (I've had to put it in pastebin since the code/text ratio was above the post requirements)

Line 121 of main.js is the `fetch('localhost:3000/session', {` line so I'm assuming I'm pointing the fetch() url to the incorrect place but I've tried every other route I can think of and they all produce 'NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource'.

I don't know if it's relevant but the fetch() function is within another on-click function that also creates the sessionObject object.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The way SO works, your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Two reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put a [mcve] **in** the question. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Separately: Look in your Network tab for the *real* error, "NetworkError" and then a line number doesn't tell us anything. At a guess, you're trying to fetch something cross-origin (from `file://` to `http://` or different ports or...) and running afoul the Same Origin Policy, but...

Comment: Use full URLs with `fetch()` that start with `http://` or `https://`.  While the browser will let you type `localhost:3000/session` into the URL bar, that is not a legal URL.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder I really tried to post a succinct version of the code but I wasn't sure what was exactly relevant to the question and the most minimal version I parred down was still too large for the code/text ratio blocking on post submission. The network tab doesn't show anything other than the GET request for jquery.

Comment: `localhost:3000/session` is incorrect, that's a page-relative URL (e.g., if you do that from `http://localhost:3000/index.html`, you're say "get `http://localhost:3000/localhost:3000/session`, which makes no sense). You probably meant `//localhost:3000/session` (which is protocol-relative but otherwise absolute) or, if you're doing this from `localhost:3000` already, just use `/session` or `session`.

Comment: @T.J Crowder I'm currently doing it from an html page saved locally so I thought I'd need to specify the server hosted on localhost. I'll try without it

Comment: @AlexVale - Don't do that. :-) (But if you did, you'd need `http://` or `https://` in front of it.) Doing that will (on some browsers, and not others) make your request fail because of the Same Origin Policy, and separately, pages loaded from file URLs behave subtly differently from ones loaded via HTTP. When doing web development, always use an actual server process.

Comment: @T.J Crowder Not using localhost etc. doesn't seem to have worked - the error is still there in the console and nothing in the network tab. When I use `https://localhost:3000/session` then the error is still in the console but in the network tab there's a recognition that a POST attempt was made

Comment: @T.J.Crowder How would I go about loading the index.html using actual server process?

Comment: If you're doing this from a page saved locally (which you said) which is loaded into the browser with a `file://` URL, then you will likely have cross-origin issues.  Don't try using ajax from `file://` web pages.  Just not worth it and not likely a real-world situation worth trying to solve either.  Put the web page in a real web server and load it into the browser from that web server and then you won't have origin issues like that.

Comment: @AlexVale - Run a local web server (perhaps even the Node.js process you're already running).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Forgive me, I'm just getting started with web development (if that wasn't already glaringly obvious). What's the best way to go about setting up a local web server and how would I incorporate the node.js process?

Comment: @AlexVale - Everyone's new sometimes! :-) But that's far too broad a question. Look at doing a local Apache or nginx install, or using [Express](http://expressjs.com) or [Koa](http://koajs.com) on Node.js (or some combination of Apache/nginx and Express/Koa, e.g., having Apache/nginx proxy certain routes, passing them on to an Express/Koa backend running on Node.js).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Okay, I've got XAMPP so I'll look into using Apache to host it. Once I've got the index.html hosted on that will I need to change anything with the API set up or can I just direct the fetch() url to `http://localhost:3000/session` again?

Comment: @AlexVale - That depends on how you have it set up. If you have both requests (the `index.html` request and the fetch) on the [*same origin*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), then yes, the fetch will work with `/session` as the URL. If you're crossing origins (which includes port number), you'll need to handle that with [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Okay. I've got CORS enabled on my API since I thought that was the inital problem so crossing origins shouldn't be a problem. I've also now got my `index.html` hooked up on apache and viewable using `localhost` - hopefully that's everything sorted now!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It seems I was overly optimistic... It seems that when I trigger the fetch() by the clicking of a button XAMPP redirects to `localhost/dashboard`